# Unanswered questions locked

Tags: discussion

Not sure where to post this reply but my original question was non-answered then locked, and labeled not useful.

[Undo and Redo on Macbook not functioning](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/undo-and-redo-on-macbook-not-functioning)

I just started using Blender on specifically on the very popular Macbook platform running Lion.  Unfortunately, the most basic of commands (undo/redo) do not work using ctrl-z. The answer given was that undo is ctrl-z, even though I specifically stated that does not work.

Every Macbook user running Lion is going to hit this problem.  The solution, it turns out is to **disable** *mission contro*l under system preferences for keyboard. I hope this helps others.

Comment: When you ask a question, please *read* the responses. The very useful answer brecht gave addresses your issue directly--use the 'Command' key instead of the 'Control' key. The comment I posted before locking your post explains exactly why it was locked: the question does not directly pertain to Blender, but instead is about the Mac OS itself. Please take a look at Superuser.SE or Ask Different for any future questions you might have on the issue.

Comment: First of all, your issue is not Blender itself, but the operating system. Most users on Blender.SE are Windows users, and if you continue to have issues you can ask in the comments. Starting a new question when it can be answered in one thread isn't optimal.

Comment: @CharlesL I'd venture to say it's probably split evenly between Linux and Windows actually :)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I use Mac 75% of the time and Linux the other 25%